# ReferenceError : AngularJS is not defined on Karma with Jasmine unit testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm actually stuck since few hours, my boss wants me to proceed to unit testing on the functionalities i coded last week, when I do my karma start `karma.conf.js` it gives me the following issue :

`"message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined",`

my files structure :

```
webapp
    -www
        -services
            api.service.js
    -test
        test.test.js
    karma.conf.js
```

essential of karma.conf.js :

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
  files: [
    'www/js/services/api.service.js',
    'test/**/*.test.js'
  ],
})
}
```

I think Karma doesn't find my api.service.js but i don't know why, the angularjs code actually work in the webapp.

content of my test.test.js :

```
(function() {
'use strict';

   describe('apiService', function() {

     it('should return an array of object', function() {
     var artist = typeof getArtist(118680); // MGMT Artist
     console.log(artist);
     expect(artist).toEqual('array');
     });
   });
})();
```

getArtist is the function I need to test situated in api.service.js.

Thank you,

Paul.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Karma needs the angular file to test angularJS code. You need to include it in the files array in the karma configuration.

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
  files: [
    'path-to-angular.js',
    'www/js/services/api.service.js',
    'test/**/*.test.js'
  ],
 })
}
```